# How can i show a "Logout Button" if i click on a icon in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I show a Logout Button when I click on my icon?

home.html:

```
<div class="icon-bar">
  <div class="logout"> 
    <img src="/Login/images/login.png" ng-model="logout">
    <div class="check-element animate-hide" ng-show="logout">
      <button>Logout</button>
    </div>
    <div class="check-element animate-hide" ng-hide="logout">
    </div>      
  </div>
<div>
```

When i click on the icon, I want the logout button to appear like a "dropdown"

I want to put the logic in a controller.

Sorry, I know it's an easy task, but I am totally new in angular js :/

Comment: The `dropdown` effect would be done in `CSS`

Comment: Here is an example, next time try to google first =). http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_select.asp 
Btw, the effect you are seeking for is not related to Angular. It is either CSS or JavaScript or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I use [**`ng-click`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick): when you will click on your image, it will change the value of `logout` (true -> false ; false -> true). Your `ng-show` / `ng-hide` will work as you expect.

```
<div class="logout"> 
    <img src="/Login/images/login.png" ng-click="logout = !logout">
    <div class="check-element animate-hide" ng-show="logout">
        <button>Logout</button>
    </div>
    <div class="check-element animate-hide" ng-hide="logout">
        logout is {{logout}}
    </div>      
</div>
```

[**Try is on JSFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/1w8L3pwm/)

Comment: even simpler, than you :)

Comment: i have try it like you, but for my example, the logout variable will not be set on true or false :O

if i test it with logout is {{logout}} the variable will not be assigned with true or false :/

Comment: `logout is {{logout}}` just prints the variable, it does not affect its value

Comment: if i clicked the image it will not shown the button :/

the logout button is not hide initial :/

https://jsfiddle.net/y2w0820f/

Comment: This code works, try the Fiddle. :) @Kai: It is not necessary, by default `logout == undefined`, `ng-show="logout"` won't be `true`.

Comment: @weedoze sorry for my stupid answer -.-

i cant get it work, dont know i am to stupid today xD

Answer (score 2):

You can add `ng-click` on the image. This will call a function that will toggle the variable `logout`.

You can also put `logout = !logout` directly inside the `ng-click` directive

The *dropdown* effect has to be done with css/js. This has nothing to do with AngularJS

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.logout = false;

  $scope.toggleLogout = function() {
    $scope.logout = !$scope.logout;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="logout" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <img src="/Login/images/login.png" ng-click="toggleLogout()">
  <div class="check-element animate-hide" ng-show="logout">
    <button>Logout</button>
  </div>
  <div class="check-element animate-hide" ng-hide="logout">
  </div>
</div>
```